# Anyone know how to Bulk Insert to SQL from string Array with comma delimited columns in Array

Tags: c#

I have a string array in C3 that gets populate with Yahoo Historical data that has data in the array like this..

```
string url = string.Format("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={0}&a=2&b=1&c=2010&d={1}&e={2}&f={3}&g=&ignore=.csv",
    SymbolSelect, CurrentMonth, Today, CurrentYear); 
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string data = web.DownloadString(url);
string[] rows = data.Split("\n".ToCharArray());
```

Array rows--->> Date,Open,Low,close,Volume,AdjClose

The array rows will have each row as stated above with 6 columns of data per row. I have no idea how to insert that into a sql table? I know how to insert to a sql table, but not like this from this array structure. Anyone know how to insert every single row of thousands with this structure??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL server technology, this may apply:

> A SQL feature (since SQL-92) is the use of row value constructors  to insert multiple rows at a time in a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO ''TABLE'' (''column-a'', [''column-b, ... '']) 
VALUES (''value-1a'', [''value-1b, ...'']), 
       (''value-2a'', [''value-2b, ...'']), 
       ...
```

> This feature is supported by DB2, SQL Server (since version 10.0 - ie. 2008), PostgreSQL (since version 8.2), MySQL, and H2.

- [Insert (SQL) - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29#Multirow_inserts)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

The only problem with that approach is that you will have to project your data into a DataTable, DataRow[], etc. in order to use SqlBulkCopy

Comment: You can actually implement IDataReader too which is a lot more efficient in many cases because you don't need to load up a table with the data if you already have it in memory in another form.

Comment: @Josh Einstein, good point about creating an IDataReader that can interpret the incoming comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading "bulk insert" as `SqlBulkCopy`. There are two ways to work with `SqlBulkCopy`. The first is to pre-process your data into a `DataTable`. This is simple and easy, but is only suitable for small-to-moderate data due to the requirement to buffer **all** the data into a `DataTable` first!

The second is to create an `IDataReader`; this is a streaming API, so can be used for huge forwards-only data sources (such as massive log files). I wrote a `SimpleDataReader` that you can see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/91c7a20056ffe8e1) (ignore the xml; focus on the usage) that I use in a few places. It works fine; all you do is:

- in the constructor, tell the *base* constructor the types for the columns
- in `DoRead` attempt to read the next row (perhaps `ReadLine` on a text-reader), and  either call `SetValues` and return `true`, or return `false` if there is no more data
- override `DoClose` if you want to clean up anything once the data is consumed (close the file, perhaps)